# How does group by work in sub queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm pretty shaky when it comes to advanced aggregate functions in SQL. I've got this query:

```
SELECT Name, avg(Value) Mean, Number
From Table1
where Category = 'Time'
group by Name, Number;
```

which is a fairly obvious in what it does. But in case, here's what that looks like:

```
|  Name  |  Mean | Number |
|:------:|:-----:|:------:|
| Thing1 | 112.6 | 1      |
| Thing2 | 111.9 | 1      |
| Thing1 | 109.1 | 2      |
| Thing2 | 99.4  | 2      |
| Thing1 | 91.8  | 3      |
| Thing2 | 80.1  | 3      |
| Thing1 | 73.7  | 4      |
| Thing2 | 47.2  | 4      |
```

Now I'd like to get the sum of these averages for a particular Number.

My thought process would be to do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Mean) Total Mean, Number 
FROM (SELECT Name, avg(Value) Mean, Number
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Category = 'Time'
    GROUP BY Name, Number)
GROUP BY Number;
```

But as is probably obvious, I get a `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'` error. What is the best way to accomplish this goal so that I get a table that looks like this:

```
| Total Mean | Number |
|:----------:|:------:|
| 224.5      | 1      |
| 208.5      | 2      |
| 171.9      | 3      |
| 120.9      | 4      |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derived table is missing an alias.

```
SELECT SUM(Mean) Total Mean, Number 
FROM (SELECT Name, avg(Value) Mean, Number
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Category = 'Time'
    GROUP BY Name, Number) t --alias for the derived table
GROUP BY Number;
```

Comment: Oh my god, is it really that easy lol. I feel very stupid. Thank you for the help! That fixed it!